# Insert PHP code into my page.xml

Tags: php, xml

page.xml.php will not show any output, in firebug I can see the get response for page.xml.php with my class responsible for extracting the data isn't seeing the content as xml data

How can i get this to work?

index.php

```
// Load config file
    $config = simplexml_load_file("resources/pinboard/config.xml.php");
```

page.xml.php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
...
<module name="Weather" id="23">
    <title>Weather</title>
    <location><?php echo $_COOKIE['zip_code']; ?></location>
</module>
...
```

weather.php

```
...
protected $default_config = array(
                'title' => 'Weather',
                'refresh' => '200000', // Every 20 minutes
                'location' => "Los+Angeles",
                'format' => 'f'
);
...
```

site.js

```
...
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "resources/pinboard/config.xml.php?" + new Date().getTime(),
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            // Parse config
            $(xml).find('settings').children().each(function(test){
                settings[$(this)[0].localName] = $(this).text();
            });

            // Call init (startup the picboard)
            init();

        }
    });
...
```

Comment: It's just a regular php file, the fact that it echos xml doesn't change this fact. Just threat it like a regular php file, like you would do with a php file that echos html.

Comment: if you have your config file *dynamic*, you're doing something **awfully** wrong

Comment: Please clarify your question. What doesn't work? What are you trying to do? What did you try so far? Even with that update, I don't see your problem.

Comment: @Gordon it's clear and obvious.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, hmmm true I would like the config to be static, but config in my case just means an xml file with module data with the data they are going to be populated with. Nothing site/system specific

Comment: Well, get rid of $_COOKIE['zip_code']; as it's not config variable and obviously it's site-specific

Comment: @Gordon refresh the page. Nanne explained it already for ones who can't see it from the code.

Comment: @Col The OP's code shown above seems unrelated. The explanation by Nanne is not an answer at all. The contents of `resources/pinboard/config.xml.php` are not shown anywhere.

Comment: @Gordon right under simplexml_load_file line. You need to take a break :)

Comment: @Col it says page.xml.php not config.xml.php and there is also no 'settings' in it that could be extracted in that Ajax call.

Comment: @Gordon ugh, well, it's me to take a break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loading your `xml.php` file with

```
$config = simplexml_load_file("resources/pinboard/config.xml.php");
```

<strike>But that would not return a parsed file, just the source. Now I don't know if your other xml.php files are loaded like that, -but you need to "go trough the webserver" for it to work.</strike>

The ajax call does seem correct though.

As suggested in the comments:

> use more sensible application structure

Comment: Nope, no need to "go trough the webserver". The op had proved that has no idea what is he doing. **Do not answer literally** godddam Stackoverflow!

Comment: My apologies for any accidental toes I stepped upon. I still think that using `simplexml_load_file` on an unparsed php file is problematic and should be fixed. I don't see what's wrong with pointing that out, but if you'd enlighten me, i'd be happy to press the delete button...

Comment: I'd be happy if you just delete "go trough the webserver" statement and advise the op to use more sensible application structure.

Comment: I agree, and will do as you suggest, although I think it is a bit of a general statement that the OP might not take to heart :)

Comment: -.- ... I may have some idea, im just experimenting with php interaction with xml files